# Winter bash 2016 - hats are live!

Tags: discussion

Hooray, hats! (Shameless plug towards a hat.)

http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/

Hat options:

- I am your father - post/vote on meta
- Running ragged - earn 150 rep on three non-SO sites in 15 days
- 011 - collect 11 hats
- Snapchat - answer in 30 minutes, +3, and accepted
- Other hats I haven't yet had time to add, I will =)

Plus secret hats, of course...

Comment: Downvote, eh? So, someone doesn't like hats.

Comment: Related Mother Meta post: [Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats).

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from my "Buche de Noel" hat (won on the 24th Dec); there appears to be a bug in the hat software!

Comment: The software probably hands out the hat one day early to accommodate 24 time zones.

Comment: This is a FAQ every year, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288735/222298

Comment: Thanks for that.